# Able to use equirectangular Projection on world map like tweetping, need to get that working for USA image also

Tags: javascript, dictionary, map-projections

Currently I am able to plot the geocodes using equi-rectangular projection on world map like tweetping site(https://tweetping.net/), but I need to get that working with US map image. I see that equi-rectangular formula work with world map image but not with US map image.

Here is my current code of equi-rectangular projection that is converting the latitudes and longitudes into css properties top and left which i am using to position the point on the world map image:

```
function projectLat (lat, height) {
  if (isNaN(lat) || typeof lat !== 'number' || lat < -90 || lat > 90) {
    throw new Error('latitude is not valid');
  }
  if (isNaN(height) || typeof height !== 'number'){
    throw new Error('viewport height is not valid');
  }
  return ((lat - 90) / -180 * height);

}
function projectLng (lng, width) {
  if (isNaN(lng) || typeof lng !== 'number' || lng < -180 || lng > 180) {
    throw new Error('longitude is not valid');
  }
  if (isNaN(width) || typeof width !== 'number'){
    throw new Error('viewport width is not valid');
  }
  return (lng + 180) / 360 * width;
}
```

I have attached the world map image as well the US image that i am using.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks so much.

[Us image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yWBX.png)

Answer (score 0):

That image won't work.  It is not projected as you need.

So, equi-rectangular projection means you stretch the north pole (which is a point) to the size of the equator (40 million meter; dito for the south pole; ignore the fact that the world is not a perfect sphere).

Then the world is a rectangle 180° high (-90 to +90), 360° wide (-180 to +180)

The consequence is that equal latitude points are on a horizontal line. equal longitude points are on a vertical line.

The USA has such lines.  Example: the border with Canada, north of Montana/Washington/N-Dakota, is a straight line, on lat = 49° North.

You need a picture where that line is straight and horizontal.